# Rounding issue in python

Tags: python, if-statement, numpy

Here is my input

```
import numpy as np

array = [0.29, 0.59, 0.12]
na_array = np.array(array)
a = np.sum([0.29, 0.59, 0.12])
print a
if (a == 1.0):
    print "success"
```

the output is:

```
1.0
```

Why isn't "success" printed?

Comment: Read [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the floats are not equal. Using `==` with floating point numbers is usually not a good idea.

[What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Its just rounding off when printing, the actual value of `a` is - `0.99999999999999989` (This is because of internal floating point representations).

Example -

```
In [13]: a = np.sum([0.29, 0.59, 0.12])

In [14]: a
Out[14]: 0.99999999999999989

In [15]: print a
1.0
```

---

This happens because -

```
In [20]: 0.29 + 0.59
Out[20]: 0.8799999999999999
```

---

If this is a real issue, you can try rounding the number before comparing -

```
In [22]: if round(a,1) == 1.0:
   ....:     print('success')
   ....:
success
```